# regex capture certain characters only

Tags: php, regex

currently dealing with a bit of a problem. this is my string "all-days"
im in need of some assistance to creating a regex to capture the first character, the dash and also the first character after the dash. Im a bit of a newbie to Regex so forgive me.

Here is what ive got so far. (^.)

Comment: What is the *system* in what you want to catch? Always the first letter, and **any** letter following a dash? Or...? If the string is always `all-days`, then this would work: `#(a)ll(-d)ays#` ... But I doubt that is the case :p

Comment: `echo preg_replace ('/^(.)[^-]*-(.).*/' , '$1-$2' , 'all-days')`

Comment: `((?:-|\b)\w)`?

Comment: `(\b\w|(?<=\w)-(?=\w))` if you want to capture the `-` separately. Or even easier is `\b(\w|-\b)`

Answer (score 1):

> capture the **first** character, the **dash** and also the **first**
>   character after the dash

With `preg_match` function:

```
$s = "all-days";
preg_match('/^(.)[^-]*(-)(.)/', $s, $m);
unset($m[0]);

print_r($m);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => a
    [2] => -
    [3] => d
)
```

Comment: This matches `---`

Comment: @ctwheels, the format should be described by the OP

Comment: Agree @Roman . It's very annoying when people point out completely irrelevant stuff and try to be the judge of a question. Leave it to OP.

Comment: @Andreas it may be annoying, but it’s likely relevant to the OP’s question and will likely produce unwanted results in odd cases. I understand the OP should be raising these sorts of things, however, it may also help others that have similar questions get appropriate answers that don’t leave them questioning why something is not working as they expect it to. I was also merely pointing out that it matches that string because maybe that *is* what the OP is looking for, and this does actually answer their question more appropriately than other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Its not **regex** but If you want just a solution as you want by other way it can be achieve by `explode`, `array_walk` and `implode`

```
$string = 'all-days-with-my-style';
$arr = explode("-",$string);
$new = array_walk($arr,function(&$a){
 $a  = $a[0];
});
echo implode("-",$arr);
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/882846

Output is : `a-d-w-m-s`

Answer (score 0):

### Code

[See code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/aAx2KT/1)

```
\b(\w|-\b)
```

For more precision, the following can be used (note that it uses Unicode groups, so it doesn't work in every language, but it does in PHP). This will only match letters, not numbers and underscores. It uses a negative lookbehind and positive lookahead, but you can understand it if you keep reading this article and break it apart one piece at a time.

```
(\b\p{L}|(?<=\p{L})-(?=\p{L}))
```

---

### Explanation

- `\b` Assert position at a word boundary
- `(\w|-\b)` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `\w` Match any word character
  - `|` Or
  - `-` Match the `-` character literally
  - `\b` Assert position at a word boundary

`\b`:

- Asserts the position in the string matches 1 of the following:

  - `^\w` Assert position at the start of the string and match a word character
  - `\w$` Match a word character and assert its position as the last position in the string
  - `\W\w` Match any non-word character, followed by a word character
  - `\w\W` Match any word character, followed by a non-word character

`\w`:

- Means a word character (*usually* defined by any character in the set `a-zA-Z0-9_`, however, some languages also accept Unicode characters that represent any letter, number, or underscore `\p{L}\p{N}_`).
- For more *precision* (depending on the use-case), you can specify `[a-zA-Z]` (for ASCII letters), `\p{L}` for Unicode letters, or `[a-z]` with the `i` flag for ASCII characters with the *case-insensitive* flag enabled in regex.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your string only contains word characters and hyphens, and doesn't have consecutive hyphens:

To remove all that isn't the first character the hyphens and the first character after them, remove all that isn't after a word boundary:

```
$result = preg_replace('~\B\w+~', '', 'all-days');
```

If you only want to match these characters, just catch each character after a word boundary:

```
if ( preg_match_all('~\b.~', 'all-days', $matches) )
    print_r($matches[0]);
```